# NMF - Subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, genomics, gene-expression, clustering

I've calculated the cophenetic coefficients for the NMF of gene expression data, but is giving error when performing the clustering information step as given below:

```
clustered_data <- NMF_estimate[[num.opt - 1]][[2]]
```

> Error in NMF_estimate[[num.opt - 1]] : subscript out of bounds

Here num.opt is `num.opt <- coph[which(coph[,2]==max(coph[-1,2])),1]` which gives 2, 5 as outputs, and NMF Estimate is a list of 6 elements.

Please suggest a solution as soon as possible.